# Sprite in not updated

Tags: python, animation, pygame, sprite

This code is supposed to animate a sprite on a background, but it is just showing the sprite without any movement. I spend a day trying to figure out the issue, traced the code (I am novice so I might overlooked something), compared the code with the original author code line by line with no result, btw the original code runs smoothly meaning that it is not a problem in my PC.

Could you help me please

```
import os
import random
import math
import pygame
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption("Platformer") #set the caption at the top of the window

BG_COLOR = (255,255,255) #White background, dont need it anymore
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1000, 640 #screen dimensions
FPS = 60
PLAYER_VEL = 5 # the speed of the player

window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT)) #set the window with sizes

def flip(sprites):
    return [pygame.transform.flip(sprite, True, False) for sprite in sprites]


def load_sprite_sheets(dir1, dir2, width, height, direction=False):
    path = join("assets", dir1, dir2)
    images = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))] #if f is a file put in the images list

    all_sprites = {}

    for image in images:
        sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load(join(path, image)).convert_alpha() #loaded transparent bg image

        sprites = []
        for i in range(sprite_sheet.get_width() // width):
            surface = pygame.Surface((width, height), pygame.SRCALPHA, 32)
            rect = pygame.Rect(i * width, 0, width, height)
            surface.blit(sprite_sheet, (0, 0), rect)
            sprites.append(pygame.transform.scale2x(surface))

        if direction:
            all_sprites[image.replace(".png", "") + "_right"] = sprites
            all_sprites[image.replace(".png", "") + "_left"] = flip(sprites)
        else:
            all_sprites[image.replace(".png", "")] = sprites
        
    return all_sprites
            



class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite): #sprite is useful for perfect pixel collision
    COLOR = (0,0,255)
    GRAVITY = 1
    SPRITES = load_sprite_sheets("MainCharacters" , "MaskDude", 32 , 32 , True)
    ANIMATION_DELAY = 3
    
    def __init__(self, x,y, width , height):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.x_vel = 0
        self.y_vel = 0
        self.mask = None
        self.direction = "left" # to record which animation to show
        self.animation_count = 0 #   
        self.fall_count = 0


    def move(self,dx,dy):
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy #here we draw only the motion calculated in the next functions
        
    def move_left(self, vel):
        self.x_vel = -vel
        if self.direction != "left":
            self.direction = "left"
            self.animation_count = 0

    def move_right(self, vel):
        self.x_vel = vel
        if self.direction != "right":
            self.direction = "right"
            self.animation_count = 0

    def loop(self , fps):
#        self.y_vel += min(1 , (self.fall_count/fps) * self.GRAVITY)
        self.move(self.x_vel,self.y_vel)

        self.fall_count += 1
        self.update_sprite()

    def update_sprite(self): #is about changing the sprite shape to look walking
        sprite_sheet = "idle"

        if self.x_vel !=0:
            sprite_sheet = "run"

        sprite_sheet_name = sprite_sheet + "_" + self.direction
        sprites = self.SPRITES[sprite_sheet_name]
        sprite_index = (self.animation_count //
                        self.ANIMATION_DELAY) % len(sprites) #set new index every ANIMATION_DELAY = 5
        self.sprite = sprites[sprite_index]          
        self.animation_count += 1

    def draw(self, win):
        #print(self.SPRITES)
        self.sprite = self.SPRITES["idle_"+self.direction][0]
        win.blit(self.sprite , (self.rect.x , self.rect.y))

    
def get_background(name): #name is bg image, this create the bg image position list
    image = pygame.image.load(join("assets", "Background", name))
    _, _, width, height = image.get_rect()
    tiles = [] #list of tles I need to fil my window bg

    for i in range(WIDTH//width + 1):
        for j in range (HEIGHT // height+1):
            pos = tuple([i * width , j*height]) # convert list into tuple
            tiles.append(pos)
        
    return tiles, image # now I now the list of positions to fill the bg and the exact file to use

def draw(window, background, bg_image, player):
    for tile in background:
        window.blit(bg_image, tile) # drawing the image at every position

    player.draw(window)

    pygame.display.update()

def handle_move(player): #check keys and collision
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    player.x_vel = 0; #as moveleft change the velocity we have to change it to zero so w
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        player.move_left(PLAYER_VEL)
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        player.move_right(PLAYER_VEL)

def main(window):
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    background, bg_image = get_background("Blue.png")

    player = Player(100,100,50,50)
    run = True
    while(run):
        clock.tick(FPS) #fix the refresh rate to this otherwise it will be dpending on the computer power

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #if teh program detect an event of the user Quiting the game
                run = False
                break
                
        player.loop(FPS)
        handle_move(player)
        draw(window, background, bg_image, player)
    pygame.quit()
    quit() #quiting the  python itself

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(window) #when we run the file go to the main function with this arg
```

comparing the code with the original author code, change my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem lies in the following line of the `Player.draw` function:

```py
self.sprite = self.SPRITES["idle_"+self.direction][0]
```

The `sprite` attribute was already set in the `update_sprite` function to the correct sprite taking the animation count and state into an account. However, this line resets it to the first image (`[0]`) from the idle spritesheet (`"idle_"`), without taking the animation count or state into an account. This does make that only this sprite and not the correct one is being drawn.

Removing the line should resolve the problem.